# Bivariate normal distribution; rotation; diagonal covariance matrix

Tags: normal-distribution, rotations

> > Let $Z\sim N(0,\Sigma)$ with 
> >     $$
> > \Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_1^2 & p\sigma_1\sigma_2\\p\sigma_1\sigma_2 & \sigma_2^2\end{pmatrix}
> > $$ 
> >     whereat $\sigma_i^2=\text{var}(Z_i), i=1,2$ and $p=\text{cov}(Z_1,Z_2)/(\sigma_1\sigma_2)$.
> >     Show that by rotation $Z$ can be transformed into a bivariate normal distribution $Y\sim N(0,D)$ with a diagonal covariance matrix $D=\text{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)$ (resp. that $Z$ emanates from such a distribution by the inverse rotation).

Hello everybody, if I got that right, I have to find a $2\times 2$-matrix $R$ which is a rotation matrix and fullfills
$$
R\Sigma=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1 & 0\\0 & \lambda_2\end{pmatrix}.
$$

I do not know how to do so. Can you please help me?

---

**EDIT** *(based on the help I got in the comments below)*

So the task is to find a rotation matrix $R$ with $RZ=Y$. So the covariance matrix $D$ of $Y$ will be of the form $D=R\Sigma R^T$.

So I started with $R=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\alpha & -\sin\alpha\\\sin\alpha & \cos\alpha\end{pmatrix}$ and determined the entries of $R\Sigma R^T$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\sigma_1^2 \cos^2\alpha-2\sin\alpha \cos\alpha p\sigma_1\sigma_2+\sigma_2^2 \sin^2\alpha & \cos\alpha\sin\alpha(\sigma_1^2-\sigma_2^2)+p\sigma_1 \sigma_2 (\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha)\\ \sin\alpha\cos\alpha (\sigma_1^2-\sigma_2^2)+p\sigma_1\sigma_2(\cos^2\alpha-\sigma^2\alpha) & \sigma_1^2 \sin^2\alpha+2p\sigma_1\sigma_2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha+\sigma_2^2\cos^2\alpha\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now I set the entries that are not on the diagonal to $0$ and solved it for $\alpha$: For both equations I got that
$$
\alpha_k=-\frac{1}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{2p\sigma_1\sigma_2}{\sigma_1^2-\sigma_2^2}\right)+k\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}, k\in\mathbb{Z}
$$

are the possible solutions. Because it is enough to find one appropriate rotation matrix I chose 
$$
\alpha_0=-\frac{1}{2}\arctan\left(\frac{2p\sigma_1\sigma_2}{\sigma_1^2-\sigma_2^2}\right).
$$
With this result I calculated the entries on the diagonal, just putting $\alpha_0$ in the above entries:
$$
\lambda_1:=\sigma_1^2\cos^2\alpha_0-2\sin\alpha_0 \cos\alpha_0p\sigma_1\sigma_2+\sigma_2^2\sin^2\alpha_0
$$
$$\lambda_2:=\sigma_1^2\sin^2\alpha_0+2\sin\alpha_0\cos\alpha_0 p\sigma_1\sigma_2+\sigma_2^2 \cos^2 \alpha_0
$$
So with the found $\alpha_0$ it is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\cos\alpha_0 & -\sin\alpha_0 \\ \sin\alpha_0 & \cos\alpha_0\end{pmatrix}\Sigma \begin{pmatrix}\cos\alpha_0 & \sin\alpha_0 \\ -\sin\alpha_0 & \cos\alpha_0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2\end{pmatrix}=D.
$$

I think that's it?

With greetings

Miro

Comment: First, find out what a rotation matrix $R$ looks like. Hint: it has entries that look like $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$. Then compute the off-diagonal entries of $R\Sigma$ and set them equal to $0$. Solve for $\theta$. Further hint: there are four possible values for $\theta$ that differ by multiples of $\pi/2$.

Comment: It is $R=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta\\\sin\theta & \cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$. So I have to solve (I.) $\cos\theta p\sigma_1\sigma_2-\sin\theta\sigma_2^2=0$ and (II.) $\sin\theta\sigma_1^2+\cos\theta p\sigma_1\sigma_2=0$ for $\theta$. How can I do so?

Comment: From (I.), can you find what $\tan \theta$ must equal in terms of the known parameters $\sigma_1, \sigma_2$ and $\rho$?  By the way, the covariance matrix is not $R\Sigma$ as you have it, but rather $R\Sigma R^T$, that is, you need to rework (I) and (II) before solving for $\theta$.

Comment: Ok, then I have to solve (I.) $\cos\theta p \sigma_1^3\sigma_2-\sin\theta p^2\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2+\cos\theta p\sigma_1\sigma_2^3-\sin\theta \sigma_2^4=0$ and (II.) $\sin\theta\sigma_1^4+\cos\theta p \sigma_1^3\sigma_2+\sin\theta p^2\sigma_1^2\sigma_2^2+\cos\theta p\sigma_1\sigma_2^3=0$. If this is right, I do not know how to solve this for $\theta$ now, to be honest.

Comment: **Bzzzzt!!** Try again. You were supposed to be finding $R\Sigma R^T$. You seem to have found $\Sigma R \Sigma^T$ instead. There are _no_ powers of $\sigma_i$ greater than $2$ in the former; there are in the latter.

Comment: Ok, you are right. (I.) $\sigma_1^2\cos\theta\sin\theta-(\sin\theta)^2 p\sigma_1\sigma_2+(\cos\theta)^2p\sigma_1\sigma_2-\sin\theta\cos\theta\sigma_2^2=0$ and (II.) $\sin\theta\cos\theta\sigma_1^2+(\cos\theta)^2 p\sigma_1\sigma_2-(\sin\theta)^2p\sigma_1\sigma_2-\cos\theta\sin\theta\sigma_2^2=0$. This is to be solved to $\theta$.

Comment: $\cos\theta\sin\theta = \frac 12 \sin 2\theta$. $\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta = \cos 2\theta$ etc.

Comment: For (I.) I get $a\cdot \sin(2\theta)+b\cdot\cos(2\theta)=0$ with $a:=\frac{1}{2}(\sigma_1^2-\sigma_2^2)$ and $b:=p\sigma_1\sigma_2$. Now my questions is how to solve this for $\theta$.

Comment: Divide by $\cos(2\theta)$ and apply the $\frac 12 \arctan(\cdot)$ function, if possible, to what is left.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thank you very much. I edited my original post and added my proof based on your help. Maybe you could have a look on it. Again_ Thanks!