Origin of the joint PDF of two bivariate normals
During the last month my statistics teacher has introduced us to joint probability functions (discrete variables) and joint pdf´s. All seemed to be very intuitive and understandable until he showed us the joint pdf of a bivariate normal distribution:

He just showed us this without any introduction. I figured out that this makes sense if the 2 variables are independent (which means $\rho=0$) and therefore $f(X_1)\times f(X_2)=f(X_{1},X_{2})=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_{1}\sigma_{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}[(\frac{X_1-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}){^2+(\frac{X_2-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}){^2}}]}$, but I don´t understand how and when $\rho$ appears when they aren´t independent. I know that quadratic form in the exponential comes from the inverse of the Variance-Covariance matrix but I think that doesn´t answer my question.
I think the answer may be very large because it seems to be very theoretical so if someone knows some book/online resource which has the theory behind this, please let me know, I will thank you a lot.

One way of looking at $(X_1,X_2)$ where they are correlated is to do a rotation to $(Y_1,Y_2)$ where $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are independent so you can find the joint pdf, and then do a rotation back.  You may find it easier if you consider $Z_1=X_1-\mu_1$ and $Z_2=X_2-\mu_2$.  There is some discussion of this rotation approach at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/819480/bivariate-normal-distribution-rotation-diagonal-covariance-matrix

Mmm... that seems pretty complex. I will try to understand it, thanks anyways!
